# Why the gradients return None and optimizer can't work

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable['conv2d_66/kernel:0', 'conv2d_66/bias:0',...]
```

The gradients always return `[None,None...,None]`

I'm trying to use DDQN and CCN to make a reinforcement learning in TensorFlow following a Pytorch Sample.

When I transplant the code,I rebuild the gradients parts.

```
def net_init(self,state,modelIndex):
    c, h, w = self.input_dim
    self.predict = Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,8,4,activation='relu',input_shape=(c, h, w),data_format="channels_first"),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 4, 2, activation='relu',padding="VALID"),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 1, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, input_shape=(3136,), activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.output_dim, input_shape=(512,), activation=None)])

    self.target = Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 8, 4, activation='relu', input_shape=(4, 84, 84), data_format="channels_first"),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 4, 2, activation='relu', padding="VALID"),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, 1, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, input_shape=(3136,), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.output_dim, input_shape=(512,), activation=None)])

    if modelIndex==1:
        # self.predict.summary()
        return self.predict(state)
    if modelIndex==2:
        self.target.summary()
        return self.target(state)



@tf.function
def train_step(self, states, actions):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(states)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.huber(states, actions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.predict.trainable_variables)
    # gradients = [tf.clip_by_norm(gradient, 10) for gradient in gradients]

    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.predict.trainable_variables))
    return loss

def train(self):
    if self.curr_step % self.sync_every == 0:
        self.sync_Q_target()
    if self.curr_step % self.save_every == 0:
        self.save()
    if self.curr_step < self.burnin:
        return None, None

    if self.curr_step % self.learn_every != 0:
        return None, None


    self.counter += 1
    state, next_state, action, reward, done = self.recall()
    current_action_qs =self.pred(state, action)
    next_action_qs = self.pred_next(next_state)
    best_action=tf.math.argmax(next_action_qs, axis=1)
    next_Q_1=self.net_init(next_state,2).numpy()[np.arange(0, self.batch_size), best_action]
    next_Q_2=(reward + (1 - done.numpy()) * self.gamma * next_Q_1)
    loss=self.train_step(next_Q_2,current_action_qs)
    # self.save_log(self.counter, np.mean(loss), "loss.csv")
    return (int(current_action_qs.mean()), loss)
```

Complete code: https://github.com/huxxshadow/test

Any advice?

Comment: What is the loss function?

Comment: The Pytorch version use the SmoothL1，but in tensorflow I only learned about the tf.keras.losses.huber which is most close to former

Comment: you need to compute states and actions inside the GradientTape, and you are not doing that.

Comment: When I tring to do like that,its still return None arrary and to do like that I need to delete the @tf.function.So may be something else going wrong.Thank you for your advice